# Калькулятор на чистом JS

Tags: javascript, html

Я недавно начал изучать JS (чистый) и решил создать калькулятор. Несколько сделать удалось, но с одним не могу разобраться вот уже 10-ый день. Хочу сделать калькулятор с четырмя параметрами (тип, модель, размер и цвет). Напирмер если пользователь нажал на один из "типов", то должны появится определённые модели, размер и цвета, после чего расчитать их стоимость, вес и габариты.

```js
var price = 0,
  models_html = "";
var cases = [
  //Type Model  Size  Weight  H * W * D  Price
  ['ABS Пластик', 'Краби', ['S', '2', 50, 34, 20, 2190],
    ['M', '2.7', 61, 43, 25, 2690],
    ['L', '3.5', 71, 49, 29, 2990]
  ],
  ['ABS Пластик', 'Бангкок', ['S', '2,2', 53, 35, 20, 2390],
    ['M', '2.7', 63, 41, 26, 2790],
    ['L', '3.5', 73, 48, 31, 3090]
  ],
  ['ABS Пластик', 'Паттая', ['S', '2,2', 56, 35, 23, 2490],
    ['M', '3', 66, 46, 23, 2890],
    ['L', '3.8', 76, 54, 30, 3190]
  ],
  ['ABS Пластик', 'Пхукет', ['S', '2,2', 58, 38, 25, 2490],
    ['M', '3', 68, 44, 28, 2890],
    ['L', '3.8', 78, 51, 32, 3190]
  ],

  ['Поликарбонат', '', ['S', '2.3', 50, 34, 20, 3190],
    ['M', '3.1', 61, 43, 25, 3690],
    ['L', '3.8', 71, 49, 29, 4090]
  ],

  ['Полипропилен', 'Сингапур', ['S', '2.9', 57, 40, 23, 4490],
    ['M', '3.8', 67, 45, 27, 5290],
    ['L', '4.6', 77, 51, 32, 5990]
  ],
  ['Полипропилен', 'Маями', ['S', '2,2', 58, 40, 21, 5490],
    ['M', '2.8', 63, 41, 26, 2790],
    ['L', '3.5', 73, 48, 31, 3090]
  ],
  ['Полипропилен', 'Madrid', ['S', '2,2', 56, 35, 23, 2490],
    ['M', '3', 66, 46, 23, 2890],
    ['L', '3.8', 76, 54, 30, 3190]
  ],
  ['Полипропилен', 'Monaco', ['S', '2,2', 58, 38, 25, 2490],
    ['M', '3', 68, 44, 28, 2890],
    ['L', '3.8', 78, 51, 32, 3190]
  ],
  ['Полипропилен', 'Moscow', ['S', '2,2', 58, 38, 25, 2490],
    ['M', '3', 68, 44, 28, 2890],
    ['L', '3.8', 78, 51, 32, 3190]
  ]
];
for (var i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
  if (cases[i][0] == 'ABS Пластик') {
    models_html += "<label for='" + cases[i][1] + "'><input type='radio' name='model' class='dn' onclick='calc()' id='" + cases[i][1] + "' value='" + cases[i][1] + "'><span class='btn btn-outline-primary'>" + cases[i][1] + "</span></label>";
  }
}
document.getElementById('models').innerHTML = models_html;

function calc() {
  var type = document.querySelector('input[name="type"]:checked').value;
  var model = document.querySelector('input[name="model"]:checked').value;
  var size = document.querySelector('input[name="size"]:checked').value;
  var price = 0;
  if (type == 'abs') {
    type = 'ABS Пластик';
  } else if (type == 'polyc') {
    type = 'Поликарбонат';
  } else {
    type = 'Полипропилен';
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
    if (cases[i][0] == type && cases[i][1] == model) {
      var index = i;
    }
  }
  if (size == cases[i][2][0]) {
    price = cases[i][2][5];
  }
  document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = price;
}
```

```html
<FORM class="catalog" id='catalog'>
  <div id="types">
    <label for="abs">
   <input type="radio" name="type" onclick="calc()" value="abs" id="abs" class="dn">
   <span class="btn btn-outline-primary">ABS пластик</span>
  </label>
    <label for="polyc">
   <input type="radio" name="type" onclick="calc()" value="polyc" id="polyc" class="dn">
   <span class="btn btn-outline-primary">Поликарбонат</span>
  </label>
    <label for="polyp">
   <input type="radio" name="type" onclick="calc()" value="polyp" id="polyp" class="dn">
   <span class="btn btn-outline-primary">Полипропилен</span>
  </label>
  </div>
  <div id="sizes">
    <label for="s">
   <input type="radio" name="size" onclick="calc()" value="S" id="s" class="dn">
   <span class="btn btn-outline-primary">S</span>
  </label>
    <label for="m">
   <input type="radio" name="size" onclick="calc()" value="M" id="m" class="dn">
   <span class="btn btn-outline-primary">M</span>
  </label>
    <label for="l">
   <input type="radio" name="size" onclick="calc()" value="L" id="l" class="dn">
   <span class="btn btn-outline-primary">L</span>
  </label>
  </div>
  <div id="colors">

  </div>
  <span class="btn btn-primary">Заказать</span>
  <div id="price">

  </div>
</FORM>
```

Когда обновляю страницу выдаётся ошибка в консоле, не могу понять из-за чего. Может поможет кто?
Вот доноры: https://myxbag.ru https://el-case.ru

Comment: В вашем коде используется элемент с id = "models", но в примере его нет, вы точно не пропустили его.

Comment: И как конкретно вы добавили JS в html?